# Jlabel, Jtextfield, Jbutton do not immediately show up in the GUI I mad

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, jtextfield

I have a problem with elements showing up on my GUI. I am creating a very simple program where I ask the user to input three different integers in three different boxes and a button to add the numbers together when it is pressed. Right now, I have created a button, a textfield, and a label but there's a problem: The button, textfield, and label does not appear on the GUI. I have to hover over the button area for it to appear and same with the textfield. The label doesn't show up at all even when I hover where it's supposed to be. Any reason why this is happening? Here's my code

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonPractice extends javax.swing.JFrame
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        JFrame box = new JFrame("Simple addition");
        box.setVisible(true);
        box.setSize(500,500);
        box.setResizable(false);
        box.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        box.add(panel);

        JTextField inputNumOne = new JTextField("Integer here");
        inputNumOne.setBounds(225,50,200,30);
        panel.add(inputNumOne);

        JLabel labelNumOne = new JLabel("First integer");
        labelNumOne.setBounds(100,50,150,50);
        panel.add(labelNumOne);


        JButton combiner = new JButton("Concactentate");
        //positioning of the button on the panel
        combiner.setBounds(175,300,125,50);

        panel.add(combiner);

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance to those who review the code!

Answer (score 0):

Call
`box.getContentPane().add(panel);`

after you've created your panel. Then call

`box.setVisible(true)` after that.

You should also not set your layout manager to null. Leaving it at the default `FlowLayout` is ok to start with.

[image]

Comment: Hello, I went ahead and removed setLayout(null) and implemented the code you suggested into my program but I'm not seeing any changes. when I use the command prompt to run the java program, it gives me an empty GUI until I hover over an area where there is supposed to be a button and textfield(the label is still not showing up for some odd reason). Could it be that I need an IDE to properly run the program?

Comment: If this has solved your issue would you mind accepting my answer. Thanks.